# C# Outlook Getting a Unique Key for Email After Moving To Folder

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I've got an app that needs to move an email, then categorize it, etc.. However, I need to be able to store a unique key to be able to get back to that item when a process is finished so that I can un-categorize it and un-flag it.

I thought I found something that I could use (`Namespace.CompareEntryIDs`) but that doesn't seem to work. I guess Outlook creates an entirely new item when you move it. I've found that the `ConversationIndex` seems to stay the same after moving it. Is that something reliable?

One thing to keep in mind is that this will be used in a group inbox, so another question I have is `Is the ConversationIndex the same for many clients or does it change based on session?`

Worse case scenario, I suppose I can use the `creation date` matched with the `senders email address`, right?

I'm new to the Outlook integration, so if I left any details that are needed out, please let me know and I'll add them!

P.S. using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` Version 15 dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this...

Note: that you will need to save the new Id

Item has a unique key, you are correct in that when its moved the unique  changes, mostly due to what you have already said.

This means that wen you move it, you simply need to re-save the unique key.

This helper updates Item with the new Item, so when you done moving, you can look up old and update with new.

keep the old key in a viable id before moving so you still have it, move it and then update the old record, with the new.

```
//note... when items are moved they receive a new ews identifier
    //when this is called, the caller should make a request to update the message id
    internal void MoveMessageToFolderInDirectory(ref Item item, FolderId folderId, string displayFolderName)
    {
        var folder = CheckFolderExistsInfolder(folderId, displayFolderName);
        var newItem = item.Move(folder);
        item = newItem;
    }
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know that ```Move()``` returns a MailItem. I like that, however I'm curious if that's the "proper" way to do something like this.